# unable to hide alert-success when clicking on close link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using the following inside my asp.net mvc web application

I am displaying an alert, but when I click on the close icon inside the message, it will not be removed?

```
<div class ="alert alert-success"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
<strong> @TempData["message"].</strong> 
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap v2.0.4 and jquery 1.11.2.

Comment: I dont think so...check it yourself http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5451/

Comment: It works [jsfiddle.net/mpo3u0n2](http://jsfiddle.net/mpo3u0n2/) with same versions of jQuery and Bootstrap, check on your custom scripts or other libraries or plugins that you're using.

Comment: so what could be causing this? i check the jquery console there is not any error...